# making errors more generic in october cms

Tags: error-handling, exception, octobercms

I am new to coding. I am trying to create a project in october cms.
My question is regarding the error handling. The errors seem to be too informative, and telling about the file name. 
For example
[error example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAZdA.jpg)

I just want to show the error and not the file. How can this be achieved. So users won't be able to see the file names.

Comment: Hmm can you share how you generate exception/error. Or what code generate it.

Comment: The error occurs when I logout of the application. But when I press back button, it shows me the last visiting page. When I click logout again, it shows me the error.(The error is expected but its revealing too much information)

Comment: I think, I got the answer for this. I was told that setting 'debug' value as false in config/app.php will solve it. I tried but it didn't work. Then I realize that in my .env file 'APP_DEBUG' was set to true as well. I set it to false and now it works. Seems we have to set both of them false than only it works. I am grateful to the person who mentioned this solution but unfortunately he deleted his answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this you need to set `debug` inside `config/app.php` to `false`. This will render a generic page when either a 404 or 500 is hit.

These templates can then be overridden by creating a `/500` (server error) and `/404` (page not found) in the CMS.

From the docs:

> ## Debug mode
>
> The debug setting is found in the `config/app.php` configuration file with the `debug` parameter and is enabled by default.
>
> When enabled, this setting will show detailed error messages when they occur along with other debugging features. While useful during development, `debug` mode should always be disabled when used in a live production site. This prevents potentially sensitive information from being displayed to the end-user.
>
> The debug mode uses the following features when enabled:
>
> - Detailed error pages are displayed.
> - Failed user authentication provides a specific reason.
> - Combined assets are not minified by default.
> - Safe mode is disabled by default.
>
> Important: Always set the `app.debug` setting to `false` for production environments.

Source: https://octobercms.com/docs/setup/configuration#debug-mode

Answer (score 0):

> Here's how you can do it:

1-Locate the config/app.php file in your October CMS installation.

2-Look for the 'debug' key in the configuration array. Set its value to true to enable debug mode:

**'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true),**

Save the changes to the App.php file.

Remember that enabling debug mode in a production environment can expose sensitive information, so it's crucial to disable debug mode when your application is live.